# Jsoncpp nested arrays of objects

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I need to search for an element in a json file using the jsoncpp library.
I can't wrap my head around how to get to the most inner array... Any thoughts?

```
{
    "key": int,
    "array1": [
        {
            "key": int,
            "array2": [
                {
                    "key": int,
                    "array3": [
                        {
                            "needed_key": int
                        }
                    ]
                }
             ]
          }
     ]
}
```

Up until now I tried something like this:

```
    const Json::Value& array1 = root["array1"];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++)
    {
        const Json::Value& array2 = array1["array2"];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < array2.size(); j++)
        {
            const Json::Value& array3 = array2["array3"];
            for (size_t k = 0; k < array3.size(); k++)
            {
                std::cout << "Needed Key: " << array3["needed_key"].asInt();
            }
        }
    }
```

But it throws:

```
JSONCPP_NORETURN void throwLogicError(String const& msg) {
  throw LogicError(msg);
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and the errors and/or unexpected behaviour you get.

Comment: I have updated the post. I know what I have by now is rubbish, but I am out of ideas :(

Comment: You iterate through an array with `int`s. So shouldn't it be something like `array2 = array1[i]["array2"]` and so on?

Comment: do you need to be checking something like `array1["key"] == key1` at any level? How do you know which element contains the next level array?

Comment: @Caleth, yes. For example if the second key is equal to a certain value, then extract the needed key. But for now that is not my focus. I just want to find a way to get any element from the inner most array. After looking all day , I think that I need to to what is called a deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `array2` with `array1["array2"]`, since `array1` contains an **array** of objects, not an object, so you should get `array2` with an index `i`, `array1[i]["array2"]` instead.

The following code works for me:

```cpp
  const Json::Value &array1 = root["array1"];
  for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
    const Json::Value &array2 = array1[i]["array2"];
    for (int j = 0; j < array2.size(); j++) {
      const Json::Value &array3 = array2[j]["array3"];
      for (int k = 0; k < array3.size(); k++) {
        std::cout << "Needed Key: " << array3[k]["needed_key"].asInt();
      }
    }
  }
```

The output looks like:

```sh
Needed Key: 4
```